# What type of symbols does AC_CHECK_LIB check for?

Tags: c, elf, autoconf

I'd like to know what type of symbols does AC_CHECK_LIB check for.

If I use `readelf -a libsomelib.so` it prints me a huge bunch of symbols of different categories, including the one I want to check for in AC_CHECK_LIB.

Nevertheless, my AC_CHECK_LIB tells that this library cannot be found. Does it maybe check for other symbols only? Such as the ones in the reloc table?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out by looking into the configure script, that AC_CHECK_LIB creates a program that uses the defined functions. This program is attempted to be compiled with the library.

In my case it failed due to an unmet dependency in the library linked in.